# What is container orchestration?

Tags: gitlab, docker-swarm, orchestration

I have a GitLab repo, which uses docker container registry.

I want to push some of built containers to production using only one button click.
I heard that Kubernetes and Docker Swarm can help me, but I don't understand what it is
Can you explain in human language what is docker swarm and how can I use it to solve my task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to push some of built containers to production using only one button click

You don't need docker orchestration for that, just docker.
More specifically, [`docker image push`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_push/) (previously [docker push](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/push/))

see "[GitLab Using Docker Build](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html)"

Container orchestration is what is needed to transition from deploying containers individually on a single host, to deploying complex multi-container apps on many machines.

That is not what you are trying to do here: you just need to push images to a registry.